# How to split this types of dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

I have created web service using flask, so add request JSON parameter but now then problem is how to split my dict into simple data

My dictionary is

```
order={
   "userid":17,
   "details":[
      {
         "productid":1,
         "eachprice":45,
         "quantity":1,
         "price":45
      },
      {
         "productid":3,
         "eachprice":749,
         "quantity":1,
         "price":749
      }
   ]
}
```

so I split like

```
for x, y in order.items():
            print(x, y)
```

but the question is how I print nested data

Comment: Can you give an example of how the output should look like?

Comment: When `y` is a single value you print it, but when `y` is another dict, you want to print its parts, just like the one you're currently printing. Sounds like a job for recursive functions.

Comment: output is       ```userid 1
details [{'productid': 1, 'eachprice': 45, 'quantity': 1, 'price': 45}, {'productid': 3, 'eachprice': 749, 'quantity': 1, 'price': 749}]```

Comment: @Grismar: yes some kind of recursion would be the most general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and not so nice (=not general) solution is this:

```
for x, y in order.items():
    print(x,y, type(y))
    if type(y) == list:                     # check if the value is a list
        for element in y:                   # loop lists
            for k, v in element.items():    # loop dictionaries within the list
                print(k,v)
```

Comment: Note that this works as long as only the top level dictionary has other dictionaries as values - if nested dictionaries also have dictionaries as values, those will just be printed verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a recipe that recursively calculates the size of an object, this recursive solution basically flattens the whole data structure to a 1-dimensional list:

```
import itertools
def unpack(object, lst=[]):
    typ = type(object)
    dict_handler = lambda d: itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.items())

    if typ is dict:
        object = dict_handler(object)       # Iterate over both keys and values when dict
    if typ in [list, set, tuple, dict, frozenset]:
        for e in object:
            unpack(e, lst)                  # Recursive call for elements in container
    else:
        lst.append(object)
    return lst
    
print(unpack(data))
```